# action text is unable to store image inside rich_text_area in case of active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have use action text as text editor in normal view where I uploaded the image inside rich_text_area and save the record then it works fine but in case of active admin rich_text_area, it uploads the image but when saves the record then parameter doesn't contain image and if I try to edit the same record again then it shows empty text area. (same will work fine with .erb)

Is there any solution ?

admin/post.rb

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs :title
    f.rich_text_area :body    
    f.actions        
  end
end
```

model/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :body
end
```

if you scaffold normally and add rich_text_area for body in erb then it works fine but in case of active admin it won't work.

Comment: It will be great if you do share code snippet.

Comment: updated post please check

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707150/action-text-with-active-admin-not-working-properly

Comment: Do you have any solution?